# Trim paths in new RIVE

Tags: web, animation, flare, rive

I'm making a loader animation by using RIVE.So in new RIVE there is no option for trim paths which was available in past RIVE. I searched about it but I didn't find anything about it.So how can we do that in new RIVE? Any way to do that? Please help me to figure this out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add trim paths to strokes in the Rive editor by clicking on the icon on the left of the stroke inspector:

[image]